# Using typescript in react，stateless component not assignable to type 'React.SFC'

Tags: reactjs, typescript

TypeScript: 2.8.3
@types/react: 16.3.14

---

The type of return in function component is `JSX.Element`, when I declare the component to `React.SFC`(alias of  `React.StatelessComponent`).

There are three errors occured：

1. `TS2322: Type 'Element' is not assignable to type 'StatelessComponent<{}>', Type 'Element' provides no match for the signature '(props: { children?: ReactNode; }, context?: any): ReactElement<any>'`
2. `TS2339: Property 'propTypes' does not exist on type '(props: LayoutProps) => StatelessComponent<{}>'`
3. `TS2339: Property 'defaultProps' does not exist on type '(props: LayoutProps) => StatelessComponent<{}>'`

---

```
interface ItemInterface {
  name: string,
  href: string,
  i18n?: string[]
}

interface LayoutHeaderItemProps extends ItemInterface{
  lang: string,
  activeHref: string,
}
function LayoutHeaderItem (props: LayoutHeaderItemProps): React.SFC{
  const {name, href, lang, activeHref, i18n} = props
  const hrefLang = /\//.test(href) ? `/${lang}` : ''
  if (!i18n.includes(lang)) return null
  return (
    <a
      className={`item${href === activeHref ? ' active' : ''}`}
      key={href}
      href={hrefLang + href}
    ><span>{name}</span></a>
  )
}

LayoutHeaderItem.propTypes = {
  lang: string,
  activeHref: string,
  name: string,
  href: string,
  i18n: array
}
LayoutHeaderItem.defaultProps = {i18n: ['cn', 'en']}
```

Comment: The return type is not a component, the function itself is component. `const LayoutHeaderItem: React.SFC<LayoutHeaderItemProps>  = (props: LayoutHeaderItemProps) => { ... }`

Comment: @AlekseyL. Thank you for your answer ^_^.

Comment: You are welcome!

Comment: @AlekseyL. Is there a particular reason why a lot of people don't write answers as answers but as a comment? I'm really curious because I see that a lot on stackoverflow

Comment: @Truntle no particular reason. Sometimes questions need clarification. Posted as an answer :)

Answer (score 17):

The return type is not a component, the function itself is a component:

```
const LayoutHeaderItem: React.SFC<LayoutHeaderItemProps> =
    (props: LayoutHeaderItemProps) => { 
        // ... 
    }
```

This question is a bit old, `SFC` deprecated in favor of `FunctionComponent` with a `FC` alias

```
const LayoutHeaderItem: React.FC<LayoutHeaderItemProps> =
    (props: LayoutHeaderItemProps) => { 
        // ... 
    }
```

Comment: In order to use `React.StatelessComponent` must ES6 Arrow Function Syntax be used?  I was hoping to use `function() {}` function declaration syntax too.

Comment: @MichaelR you can't use it with function as is. Relevant suggestion [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/22063). If you really have to use a function you'll need to type parameters and return type separately (`Parameters` and `ReturnType` helpers can be used)